# bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6 Java error

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, lwjgl, slick2d

I am making a game based of of slick right now but every time I compile it I get a bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6 error. It compiles though and I can find it in the dist folder but whenever I run the .jar absolutely nothing happens.

I have the dist folder zipped up and uploaded here so you can look at it.

http://dementedgames.site88.net/Zips/Tesr.zip

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I ran this code in the command line to test it and I get this error.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Kyle>java -jar "C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Lawu\dist\Lawu
.jar"
test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.libr
ary.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
        at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)

        at lawu.Lawu.main(Lawu.java:29)

C:\Users\Kyle>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I run the .jar, I get a "No lwjgl in java.library.path" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588799/when-i-run-the-jar-i-get-a-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path-error)

Comment: Functional duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816423/warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-5