# Can't find LWJGL library (UnsatisfiedLinkError) on start

Tags: java, lwjgl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When I run the .jar, I get a “No lwjgl in java.library.path” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588799/when-i-run-the-jar-i-get-a-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path-error)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
    at shitstartdisplay.gendisplay(shitstartdisplay.java:8)
    at shitstartdisplay.main(shitstartdisplay.java:29)
```

Eclipse says, that syntax is correct, however after running the program it displays error above. Help?

Comment: Please. Use. Search .. First.

Answer (score 1):

The first page google finds when googling for the error you are receiving, is from the official documentation to lwjgl.

http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Downloading_and_Setting_Up_LWJGL

This page says:

**I keep getting an java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path**

This is because the native part is not setup correctly. Add a -Djava.library.path=path/to/dir to the commandline or as an VM option in your IDE so that lwjgl is able to find the folder containing the native files.