# When I try to launch Minecraft with Intellij I keep getting an error

Tags: java

when I try to launch Minecraft with Intellij I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in
java.library.path at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) at
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) at
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) at
org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72) at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66) at
org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:96) at
org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117) at
net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:2995) at
net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:39) at
Start.main(Start.java:11)
```

For me (I am not very familiar with java. I started like a week ago) it sounds like there is a file missing. But for me it looks like everything is at its place.

My dependencies:

[image]

Can anyone help me?
Thank you for reading this.

Mijasch

Comment: Can we have a code sample ? Would sure help identifying the problem, to see what you're doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError': no lwjgl in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344914/getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path)

Comment: You need to edit your BuildPath of the project to be sure that all needed lwjgl Folders are included.