# (using eclipse) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm having problems running a lwjgl program using eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
```

Do I need to specify the library path in the VM?
I think I imported the jar correctly, because there are no errors until the program is run.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I run the .jar, I get a "No lwjgl in java.library.path" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588799/when-i-run-the-jar-i-get-a-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path-error)

Comment: You need to link the native files to your program as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check this thread, it worked for me. It's also in the actual specs for downloading.

[Getting 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError': no lwjgl in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344914/getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path)

Installing with Eclipse - 
http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse